# Multithreading template member function error

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm testing how to create a thread using this code but I'm stuck with this error.

```
In file included from rasterization.cpp:1:
rasterization.h: In instantiation of 'void pipeline3D::Rasterizer<Target_t>::render_object(pipeline3D::Object<Triangle, type, Vertex_Shader>) [with type = char; Vertex_Shader = my_shader; Triangle = Triangle; Target_t = char]':
rasterization.cpp:97:40:   required from here
rasterization.h:130:17: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, pipeline3D::Rasterizer<char>*, Vertex&, Vertex&, Vertex&, my_shader&)'
     std::thread t1(&Rasterizer::render_triangle, this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
```

I don't understand why it's saying that the function is overloaded because it's the only one with that name in the file. I couldn't find any similar questions featuring templates, I tried a bunch of different solutions taken from here but I always get the same error.

The creation of the thread is with this code.
Thr is the lambda version I tried, but it also doesn't work. This is the error with the lambda version

```
rasterization.h: In member function 'void pipeline3D::Rasterizer<Target_t>::render_object(pipeline3D::Object<Triangle, type, Vertex_Shader>)':
rasterization.h:128:27: error: expected primary-expression before '(' token
     auto thr = std::thread( [this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader] { render_triangle( o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader); } );
                           ^
rasterization.h:128:37: error: expected ',' before '.' token
     auto thr = std::thread( [this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader] { render_triangle( o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader); } );
                                     ^
```

```
template<class type, class Vertex_Shader, class Triangle>
        void render_object(Object<Triangle, type, Vertex_Shader> o){
            int size = o.meshsize;
            
            
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                //auto thr = std::thread( [this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader] { render_triangle( o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader); } );
                //thr.join;
                std::thread t1(&Rasterizer::render_triangle, this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
                t1.join();
                //render_triangle(o.mesh[i].v1,o.mesh[i].v2,o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
            }
        }
```

The function render_triangle is:

```
template<class Vertex_Shader, class Vertex>
        void render_triangle(const Vertex &V1, const Vertex& V2, const Vertex &V3, Vertex_Shader shader){
//do work
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: "I don't understand why it's saying that the function is overloaded" - I don't see that it does. Can you make a minimal self-contained example and/or post full errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that it can't deduce the template argument types when using that constructor of `std::thread`. Maybe try something like this instead:

```
std::thread t1([this, &o]() {
    render_triangle(o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
});
```

Alternatively if you don't want to go the lambda route, you could explicitly tell it what the types are:

```
std::thread t1(&Rasterizer::render_triangle<Vertex_Shader, /*whatever the Vertex type is*/>, this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
```

Comment: Thanks the lambda version works but in the other solution Vertex is a template type and I don't know what type it is

Comment: Is `Vertex` the same as `type`? You could use `decltype(o.mesh[i].v1)` perhaps - though there might be issues with that too? It looks like the type is `Vertex` based on the error message

Answer (score 2):

You can't take the address of a template. You can only take the address of an instantiation. In your case you have to supply the template arguments:

```
 std::thread t1(&Rasterizer::render_triangle<decltype(o.mesh[1]), Vertex_Shader>, this, o.mesh[i].v1, o.mesh[i].v2, o.mesh[i].v3, o.shader);
```

Maybe you have a nicer name for the decltype, but your code doesn't show `mesh` either.

Comment: I edited with the full errors. Mesh is a vector of triangles(template type Triangle)